# Issue when centering vertically with flexbox when heights are unknown

Tags: css, flexbox, height, overflow

My layout has a container `flex-container` and a child.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

The container and the child have an **unknown height**. And the goal is:

- If the child has a lower height than the container, it appears centered horizontally and vertically.
- If the child has a greater height than the container, it adjusts to the top and the bottom and we can do scroll.

Scheme:
[image]

The fastest way for centering a element with flexbox is the follow:

```css
.flex-container
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertical */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal */

  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; /* for example purposes */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #2a4;
}

.flex-container > div
{
  background: #E77E23;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit voluptas eius nemo similique aperiam quis ut! Ipsa aspernatur rem nesciunt est sed hic culpa nisi delectus error explicabo reprehenderit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit voluptas eius nemo similique aperiam quis ut! Ipsa aspernatur rem nesciunt est sed hic culpa nisi delectus error explicabo reprehenderit. </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://www.codepen.io/ces/pen/slicw

But, if the container's child have a greater height, the child is not shown correctly. The child appears cutted (only the top part).

```css
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // vertical
  justify-content: center; // horizontal
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #2a4;
}

.flex-container > div
{
  background: #E77E23;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit voluptas eius nemo similique aperiam quis ut! Ipsa aspernatur rem nesciunt est sed hic culpa nisi delectus error explicabo reprehenderit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit voluptas eius nemo similique aperiam quis ut! Ipsa aspernatur rem nesciunt est sed hic culpa nisi delectus error explicabo reprehenderit. </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://www.codepen.io/ces/pen/sGtfK

Scheme:

[image]

Is there a way for resolve this issue?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex; /* only */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.flex-container > div {
    margin: auto; /* horizontal and vertical align */
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; /* change height to 300px */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #2a4;
}

.flex-container > div {
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
    background: #E77E23;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit voluptas eius nemo similique aperiam quis ut! Ipsa aspernatur rem nesciunt est sed hic culpa nisi delectus error explicabo reprehenderit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit voluptas eius nemo similique aperiam quis ut! Ipsa aspernatur rem nesciunt est sed hic culpa nisi delectus error explicabo reprehenderit. </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ces/pen/Idklh

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once - it's not only useful it's also very well communicated, thanks.

Comment: Here `.flex-container` has the initial value `align-items: flex-start` (i.e. top).

Comment: Been trying to find answer to this for a longgg time now! thank you.

Comment: Nice solution but is there a why?

Comment: @jiyinyiyong - here are some details on the "why?" ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/3597276

Comment: Nice! But are there any IE11 fixes that you can put in?

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved me HOURS of research and frustration.

Comment: It doesn't work horizontally. But if you use a min-width instead of width on the child. it works like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately setting margin to auto still doesn't fix the problem if `flex-wrap: wrap;` and the flex item is `flex: 1 100%;`. In this situation, the margin of the flex item remains 0! How can we fix the problem here?

Comment: 3 years later and you save my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `justify-content: center` or `align-items: center`. To achieve center alignment, just put empty elements on either side and set the empty elements to `flex: 1`, so that they push the center element to the center.

Answer (score -1):

Add `align-self:flex-start;` to `.flex-container > div` can resolve this problem too.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Comment: This answers the question instead of providing a workaround like the accepted answer does. +1

Comment: Your solution is simply to ignore the centering requirement. Of course, if centering wasn't necessary, there wouldn't be a problem..

Comment: This is not the correct answer because it ignores the vertical centering. So it is not a solution.