# Top overflow is unscrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I can't figure out why following snippet wont let me scroll all the way up. Inner container seems to exceed outer one, but this overflow is partially ignored. What is causing this?

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner>div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>heck 1</div>
    <div>heck 2</div>
    <div>heck 3</div>
    <div>heck 4</div>
    <div>heck 5</div>
    <div>heck 6</div>
    <div>heck 7</div>
    <div>heck 8</div>
    <div>heck 9</div>
    <div>heck 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching I found solution I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538100/issue-when-centering-vertically-with-flexbox-when-heights-are-unknown), turns out in flexbox auto margins also work vertically. Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 2):

Flex is killing you. Just remove that and align normally - flex messes with overflows.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
}


.inner>div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>heck 1</div>
    <div>heck 2</div>
    <div>heck 3</div>
    <div>heck 4</div>
    <div>heck 5</div>
    <div>heck 6</div>
    <div>heck 7</div>
    <div>heck 8</div>
    <div>heck 9</div>
    <div>heck 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the inner container a height..

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner>div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>heck 1</div>
    <div>heck 2</div>
    <div>heck 3</div>
    <div>heck 4</div>
    <div>heck 5</div>
    <div>heck 6</div>
    <div>heck 7</div>
    <div>heck 8</div>
    <div>heck 9</div>
    <div>heck 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're avoiding the overflow problem that way (didn't think about that, nice), though that may be a valid solution. You'll get my vote if OP decides this is what he prefers (I thought overflow is a must).

Comment: I actually need the overflow, content would be too squished that way, so I'm afraid this approach is no go.